# Unable to integrate $\int \sin^2(t)$ by substitution.

Tags: integration

I guess I either must be doing a stupid mistake or (more likely) I still don't really understand what's behind integration by substiution.

So I am trying to integrate $\int \sin^2(t) \mathrm{d}t$. I am mostly wondering about what I am doing wrong and less about what the correct solution would be.

So I start out with $u=\sin^2(t)$. The differentiation rules yield $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}t = 2\sin(t)\cos(t)$. So it's $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sin(t)\cos(t)}$.

But if I try substitution with this right now I get a wrong result (I verified with Mathematica that it's wrong):

$\int \sin^2(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int \frac{u \mathrm{d}u}{2\sin(t)\cos(t)} = \frac{u^2}{4 \sin(t)\cos(t)} = \frac{\sin(t)^4}{4 \sin(t)\cos(t)} = \frac{\sin(t)^3}{4 \cos(t)}$.

What have I done wrong? Can I only integrate by substitution if there remains no variable in $\mathrm{d}u/\mathrm{d}t$? Or is there another criteria?

Comment: $u$ is a function of $t$. You cannot take any term containing $t$ outside the integral.

Comment: use the double angle formula instead.

Comment: It's the wrong kind of substitution for this problem.  The usual dictum is to use the double angle formula when even powers of sine (or cosine) are present (odd powers can be handled by using some version of the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$).

Comment: [Or using Euler's formula](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/319968/201168) (which is essentially the same, in this case, as using the Double-Angle formula).

Comment: $\mathrm{d}t=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sin(t)\cos(t)}$ is not good enough. For substitution to work, the right side needs to be expressed **entirely** in terms of u.

Comment: @GoodDeeds I now realized that this is wrong. Initially I wrongly believed this was part of "integration by substitution", but uf course that doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @StevenGregory As far as I understand a $\mathrm{d}t$ like this wouldn't have been an issue if the terms containing $t$ would have cancelled out (but here they didn't so it's an issue).

Comment: @Pikachu : Yes. That is what I should have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Use the following trig identity:

$$\sin^2(t) = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos(2t))$$

**Remarks**

The reason why you are having difficulty with substitution is mostly because $u$-substitution is not suited for this problem. $u$-substitution is used to replace a difficult integral with a much easier one. For instance, the following integral looks "difficult"

$$\int 18x^2 (6x^3 +  5)^{\frac{1}{4}} \mathrm{dx}$$

until you realize you can substitute $u = 6x^3 + 5$ and the problem now becomes much easier to solve. In your case, when you do any kind of substitution you get a much more complex integral. Furthermore, when you use substitution you to have make sure the entire integral is made in terms of your substitution variable.

For instance you have:

$$\int \sin^2(t) \mathrm{d}t = \int \frac{u \mathrm{d}u}{2\sin(t)\cos(t)} = \frac{u^2}{4 \sin(t)\cos(t)} = \frac{\sin(t)^4}{4 \sin(t)\cos(t)} = \frac{\sin(t)^3}{4 \cos(t)}$$

If the substitution was done correctly then your entire right side would be in terms of $u$.

As a general rule of thumb, if you use $u$-substitution and get a much more complex integral than the one you started with then the technique is most likely not suitable. Furthermore, you have to make sure that the resulting integral is only in terms of your substitution variable.

Comment: I was aware that there was an easier way using trigonometric identities, but I think that only now I understand what was wrong with my "substitution". So basically I can only use it if I find an appropriate substituent and all other occurences of my variable get cancelled out this way. So integration by substitution is actually a bit less magic than I initially thought. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @Pikachu Yes, exactly! I think integration by parts is more magical and more powerful. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

By partial integration rule:
$$\int \sin(x)^2 dx = \int \sin(x) \sin(x) dx = -\cos(x)\sin(x) + \int \cos(x)^2 dx = -\cos(x)\sin(x) + \int (1-\sin(x)^2)dx = -\cos(x)\sin(x) + x - \int \sin(x)^2dx$$
It follows:
$$2\int \sin(x)^2dx= -\cos(x)\sin(x) + x \Leftrightarrow\\
\int \sin(x)^2dx = \frac{-\cos(x)\sin(x)+x}{2}$$

This way of calculating an integral works for many trigonometric integrals, so it's worth remembering.